# Android class structure for json with multiple elements

Tags: java, android, json

I have an Android application that gets a json from a http call and looks like this:

```
{
   "string_1":{
      "prop_1":"value",
      "prop_2":"value"
   },
   "string_2":{
      "prop_1":"value",
      "prop_2":"value"
   },
   ...
   "string_n":{
      "prop_1":"value",
      "prop_2":"value"
   }
}
```

Here's the java class I wrote to use the data in my code:

```
public class FooClass implements Serializable {
    private LinkedHashMap<String, FooObject> objectsMap;

    public LinkedHashMap<String, FooObject> getObjectsMap() {
        return objectsMap;
    }
}
```

where FooObject is:

```
public class FooObject implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("prop_1")
    private String property1;

    @SerializedName("prop_2")
    private String property2;

    public String getProperty1() {
        return property1;
    }
    public String getProperty1() {
        return property1;
    }
}
```

But since my json doesn't have an element called "objectsMap" my linked hash map from FooClass is always null. 
What class structure should I use for this json structure?
Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
I have managed to solve my problem. I use retrofit 1.9, and make the method return a result of type LinkedHashMap and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Better and more feasible is to change your response structure and have an Array rather than `string_1, string_2... string_n`. If you can't do that you will have to iterate through all the possible keys and save the response something like this

```
jObject = new JSONObject(response);
Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

while( keys.hasNext() ) {
    String key = (String)keys.next();
    if ( jObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {
         // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("string_1")
@Expose
private String1 string1;
@SerializedName("string_2")
@Expose
private String2 string2;
@SerializedName("string_n")
@Expose
private StringN stringN;

public String1 getString1() {
return string1;
}

public void setString1(String1 string1) {
this.string1 = string1;
}

public String2 getString2() {
return string2;
}

public void setString2(String2 string2) {
this.string2 = string2;
}

public StringN getStringN() {
return stringN;
}

public void setStringN(StringN stringN) {
this.stringN = stringN;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.String1.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class String1 {

@SerializedName("prop_1")
@Expose
private String prop1;
@SerializedName("prop_2")
@Expose
private String prop2;

public String getProp1() {
return prop1;
}

public void setProp1(String prop1) {
this.prop1 = prop1;
}

public String getProp2() {
return prop2;
}

public void setProp2(String prop2) {
this.prop2 = prop2;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.String2.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class String2 {

@SerializedName("prop_1")
@Expose
private String prop1;
@SerializedName("prop_2")
@Expose
private String prop2;

public String getProp1() {
return prop1;
}

public void setProp1(String prop1) {
this.prop1 = prop1;
}

public String getProp2() {
return prop2;
}

public void setProp2(String prop2) {
this.prop2 = prop2;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.StringN.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class StringN {

@SerializedName("prop_1")
@Expose
private String prop1;
@SerializedName("prop_2")
@Expose
private String prop2;

public String getProp1() {
return prop1;
}

public void setProp1(String prop1) {
this.prop1 = prop1;
}

public String getProp2() {
return prop2;
}

public void setProp2(String prop2) {
this.prop2 = prop2;
}

}
```

Hope it helps and you can use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: I went to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and it's useful if you have 2-3 objects, you can declare them and use them as shown abive, but if you have hundreds (countries list in my case) this approach is not optimal.

Comment: yes you are right but in that case it can be applied. Anyhow once you have json if it may contains thousands of objects this tool can do the work you just need to create the class and copy paste you are good to go. But yes you are right this is not a good approach for larger data you can go with generic classes. You can use libraries for further serialization and deserialization instead of writing whole thing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `SerializedName` annotation in your Response class which you're trying to map, just delete it and map your Json Response to

```
public class FooClass implements Serializable {
    private Map<String, FooObject> objectsMap;

    public Map<String, FooObject> getObjectsMap() {
        return objectsMap;
    }
}
```